# How I can import / export Big Query tables directly from Polars API

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, python-polars

I've recently start working with polars API in python and pretty much satisfied with what it can achive.

Now I need to integrate some processes with Big Query. I'll be writing some results and reading raw data aswell.

Polars very own documentation on the topic is practically non existent and of course I would like to avoid a solution in the like of

```
polars.DataFrame().to_pandas()
```

and then using pandas methods described in gcp docs.

There is a polars native solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some time has passed and I haven´t recived any input, I´m posting what have worked for me so far.

First adress the issue of uploading data to BigQuery, a Load job in GCP terms :

```
# import relevant libraries, make sure these are installed
# Also for gcp api you need to register credentials

import polars as pl
from google.cloud import bigquery as bq

# load local data into polars
my_data = pl.scan_csv("my_local_data.csv")

# Execute polars computations
# further data procesing before this step
my_data.collect()

# Save results as parquet
# This result in a smaller file size 
# and will keep intact your schema 
my_data.write_parquet("my_data.parquet")

# Create BQ client
bq_client = bq.Client()

# Set ID of you table in the cloud
table_id = "my-project.MY_DATASET.my_table"

# Set configurations for the load job
job_config = bq.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format=bq.SourceFormat.PARQUET
)

# Open the data a binary 
with open("my_data.parquet", "rb") as f:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(f, table_id, job_config=job_config)

# Execute the job
job.result()
```

As you see, this is really strightforward, and the cost of having an intermediate .parquet file is not really that much compared to the benefit of not having to deal with a schema and potential problems with data types conversion.

To address dowloading of data or a Query job in GCP terms:

```
import polars as pl
from google.cloud import bigquery as bq

# Instance a bq client
client = bq.Client()

# Write the query as a multiline string
# Note that the data source is in this very query
query = """SELECT * FROM `my-project.MY_DATASET.my_table`"""

# Execute de Query Job
# Parse it to arrow format
# Wrap all in a polars I/O function
my_cloud_table = pl.from_arrow(client.query(query).to_arrow())

# You are readu to go
```

This integration of polars with google cloud platafrom have been seamless so far in the sense of data type compatibility, null handling, etc. I wonder if there will be any gain in trying to pass binary results directly to polars and avoid arrow.

Hope someone find's this useful

Answer (score 4):

I see that the google bigquery client library has a `to_arrow` method.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/pull/8693

I cannot find any reference guide in their docs, so I am unsure if this works.

But I expect it to be something like this:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
import polars as pl

client = bigquery.Client()

# Perform a query.
QUERY = (
    'SELECT name FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` '
    'WHERE state = "TX" '
    'LIMIT 100')
query_job = client.query(QUERY)

pl.from_arrow(query_job.to_arrow())
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I wonder if there is a equivalente way todo write data in BQ. Couldn´t find any compelling instructions on documentation

Answer (score 0):

To get data you can use
[ConnectorX](https://sfu-db.github.io/connector-x/databases/bigquery.html) with [polars](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_database.html)

Comment: As far as I understand, this will allow me only to retrive (import / read) data from BQ but not write from my local enviroment to BQ.